# How to make relative redirect to Authorization Endpoint in Spring OAuth?

Tags: spring-boot, authorization, spring-webflux, spring-oauth2

I configured a service with `oauth2Login`.

User is redirected to Authorization Endpoint - `/oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}` when he/she is not authorized.

I would like to customize redirection in a way that it takes into account path prefix, since application is accessible trough prefix `/api/myapp/`.

From the source code I can see that there is `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter` during Spring Security setup and this filter is using `DefaultServerRedirectStrategy` which decides if location is relative or not. Moreover it uses a `contextPath` which is hard to set when using Spring Boot.

Unfortunately I don't know how to override default behavior to make redirect relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't need to modify `contextPath`. Instead I've registered `ForwardedHeaderTransformer` as a bean.

This transformer is able to retrieve headers set by proxy (`X-Forwarded-Prefix`) and sets context path for request correctly.

Comment: could you share some code? I have trouble registering this ForwardedHeaderTransformer, i'm not using WebFlux, just Web and every example so far use WebFlux. my frontend and backend is hosted behind the same host. my front is using / (and doing the reverse proxy) and my backend is behind /api. BUT my API has a simple context `/`, so I stripped the context when redirecting but when I try to access backend, it redirects me to login page without the `/api`. I'm  a bit stuck

Comment: I think you should not user `ForwardedHeaderTransformer` for non reactive scenarios. Have you tried adding `/api` as your context path?

Comment: I've tried but in the end I've added a proxy in front that handle the auth and forward jwt. it's all good now. Also check out this new release: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#new

Comment: @TecHunter what it brings regarding topic we've discussed?

Comment: this release brings a lot of cool stuff for OAuth, you can also find stuff for proxy here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-proxy-server